# Is it possible for me to learn music from DAW?

Tags: beats, daw

I want to learn music but dont know any basics and dont have any instruments. Is it possible for me to learn from DAW.

Comment: It is, as long as you have a way of playing the built-in instruments "live", like a keyboard or an MPC-style drumpad, or preferably something which combines the two. The easiest DAW is probably Reason. Buy second-hand and/or older versions if your budget is limited.

Comment: @YourUncleBob Any alternative for Windows PC?

Comment: Reason is available for both Mac and Windows. I'd suggest starting with a second hand copy of version 4, which just has a couple of synths, samplers, effects, and a basic mixer, with a simple layout and workflow; or version 5 if you want to record audio tracks. (Later on they integrated the sequencing and audio recording, and added a more sophisticated mixer and plug-ins, and things got more complicated.) And get something like the M-Audio Code 25 or Alesis VI 25.

Comment: Finally got Novation LaunchKey 61 MK2. Was bit comfortable with finger training but still unable to understand how to play any music, what are the possibilities to learn from online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably possible to learn just from using a DAW, but I wouldn't think it would be the easiest way to learn. Most DAW software isn't at all suitable for beginners and doesn't 'help' you a lot - DAWs are complicated and you need a lot of knowledge in music and sound engineering to be able to get them to do what you want.

Also, most people who use DAW software do use an instrument - e.g. a MIDI controller such as a MIDI keyboard - to play in the sequences that they are making. The alternative is just to enter notes with the mouse in the DAW, and this can work, but I wouldn't want that to be my only way to get notes in.

If you're really a beginner, I wouldn't personally recommend starting with a DAW. One way to begin might be to start with learning the keyboard, which is a good instrument to know for composers. Or if you want to dive straight in with making beats, why not look at getting a sequencing sampler like an Akai MPC, or a Korg Volca sample, or a Elektron Model:Samples ? All of these will probably be more fun, focused, and easier to use for a beginner. You could probably even get an app for your phone or iPad that has similar functionality for beat making.

Answer (score 0):

I taught myself music completely from scratch through a DAW.

I downloaded the demo version of Reason (which can only be open for 20 minutes) and proceeded to test which intervals sounded nice and which didn't, whether at the same time or sequentially. After that, I graduated to trying combinations of 3 or more notes (you know, chords), and in combination with a bit of wikipedia learned a couple of basic chord progressions that sound nice.

The synths themselves were complicated and overwhelming, and it took a lot of random fiddling for me to figure out what the purpose of each module was. By listening to and tweaking the demo songs and systematically taking apart the sample patches I was slowly able to figure out what each bit did. There were a few hurdles along the way, for instance the 'attack' slider sounded like it would transform my sound into something meaty and aggressive, so I was suprised when it appeared to remove it altogether.

By starting off just fiddling around randomly and then following some simple DAW-specific tutorials on how to make certain sounds, and some wikipediaing about certain chords you can give yourself a surprisingly good basic foundation.